# Implicit declaration of a function 'clock'

Tags: c, time, kernel

Hello every one I am writing a kernel module and want to find the clock cycles of a particular function. I have included the library `#include </linux/time.h>` then declared

```
clock_t c0;

c0 = clock();
```

but I am getting the error

> implicit declaration of a function `clock`

Can any one help me solve this problem?

I am using gcc on Linux.

Comment: Can you provide us with some more of your code?

Comment: sure but the code is about 1000 lines :(

Comment: can't you use, before and after, `gettimeofday` defined in `sys/time.h`? it will be inaccurate at the end of the day though.

Comment: actually i want to find cpu cluck cycles

Answer (score 7):

The function `clock` is in libc. By definition, when you're developing for the kernel **you don't have access to `libc` functions** (look up "freestanding environment").

Comment: ok thanks but is there a function or library that gives the cpu cycles of functions in kernel module thanks

Comment: @mainajaved Look for `get_cycles`. You can also use `jiffies` but watch out for preemption.